# What is OAuth 2.0 and what is the difference between Oauth Authentication and Authorization

Tags: oauth2

Please give me a brief idea about the Oauth authorization and authentication and what are the different ways of using OAuth.

Answer (score 2):

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/OAuth

> OAuth 2.0 is the next evolution of the OAuth protocol which was originally created in late 2006. OAuth 2.0 focuses on client developer simplicity while providing specific authorization flows for web applications, desktop applications, mobile phones, and living room devices.
>
> **Authentication verifies who you are.**
>
> **Authorization verifies what you are authorized to do.**

In sfdc oauth 2.0 Authorization is decided by Remote Access/connected Apps that we configure